# Perl: Undefined subroutine &main::gmdate?

Tags: perl

Here is what I'm trying to do (nothing complex):

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);

$apikey = '1234';  
$secret = '123';  
$timestamp = gmdate('U');
$sig = md5($apikey . $secret . $timestamp);

echo $sig
```

So, the error occurs on the $timestamp = gmdate line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`gmtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) function, not the `gmdate` function.  Although, now that I see that you are passing `'U'` into it, I am confused.

Ah, I see now, PHP uses `gmdate('U')` the same way Perl 5 uses `gmtime()`.

Whoops, my memory failed, you need to use [`Time::Local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) or [`POSIX::mktime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) to turn the result of `localtime` or `gmtime` into the epoch seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw/mktime/;
use Time::Local qw/timegm/;

print "the time is now ", timegm(localtime()), " or ", mktime(gmtime()), "\n";
```

Comment: is there a difference? are you sure? why am I getting the error?

Comment: oh... it's a php thing... hmm